# Need to Select DateTime Range in MySQL

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a **txn** (transaction) table which has a datetime field named **post_ts**, which is the field that represents the date of the transaction.
I am writing the code for a batch job (which is supposed to be a weekly job to be run on Sundays) using Spring Batch, and I need to run the query such that I need to fetch all transactions from a week back to the date I am running the job.

Apart from other million business rules to be applied to the query, I need the transactions from (currentdate) to (current date - 7)

Answer (score 3):

You can user mysql DATEDIFF function to achieve this :

```
SELECT * 
FROM txn 
WHERE DATEDIFF( CURDATE( ) , `post_ts` ) <= 7;
```

Comment: Thank you!
I have to use this condition in an AND clause though. Will check this out.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need more precision that the date part (no hours, minutes nor seconds to be taken into account), then you can use the function `DATEDIFF`:

```
SELECT *
FROM txn
WHERE DATEDIFF( NOW(), post_ts ) <= 7;
```

**EDIT**: I've changed the answer. It was mistaken, as I first used the `TIMEDIFF` function instead of `DATEDIFF`.

`TIMEDIFF` gives the difference in hours, minutes, ... whereas `DATEDIFF` gives the difference in the date part, ignoring the hour:minutes:seconds part.

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
    *
from 
    txn
where
    TO_DAYS(NOW()) - TO_DAYS(post_ts) <= 7;
```